# Pressing Enter to Submit an Input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, automation

how do you press enter through the use of programming to submit a textbox. Keep in mind that this is not a forum, so .submit() wont work. If this is not possible through java script, then a library or programming language to help me with this.

Comment: Bind a function to onkeyup event of the input box then check the code to see if its 13 (for enter).   You can then handle your submit without more information I cant help you on that.

Comment: What i'm trying to do Is have java script send the enter key into the text box to submit it for me. I don't wanna have to press enter myself.